# browser compatibility issues-css

Tags: css

I am getting this display in IE 7

[image: IE 7 Display]

I am getting this display in Firefox:

[image: Display in Firefox]

for the following code

[image]

Could anybody point me, What I should do to make the IE Display simalar to Firefox and also, How Do I make the Size should be same for all the headings?

Comment: Two words, [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Enhancement)

Comment: Just a couple notes: your base `box-shadow` and `border-radius` calls should be after their vendor-specific counterparts, and the latest Webkit browsers no longer use the `-webkit-gradient()` syntax, but the more standardized `-webkit-linear-gradient()`, and there's now a standard `linear-gradient()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support `gradients`, `shadows`, nor `border-radius` properties. `border-radius` is supported in IE9, but this won't be of much help!

You can look into [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/), which uses IE-specific .htc files to achieve almost the same effect.

For now, if you *really* need to be fully compatible with all IE's (and other browsers for that matter) I'd use an image. It's not very nice but at least you can rest assured that it will always work ;-)

Comment: IE9 doesn't support gradients either. IE10 does however.

Comment: Forgot they only did *some* CSS3 things, fixed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rounded corners and drop shadow aren't going to work in IE7 without a lot of clever image tricks. You can't fix it through CSS alone.

Alternatively you could probably find a JavaScript plugin which would create these effects for you if you don't mind taking that route (see [curvy corners](http://test) for example).